# python flake8 ignore E501 and max-line-length

Tags: python, pep8, pycodestyle

what is the purpose of using both

```
[flake8]
ignore = E501
max-line-length = 120
```

i have seen lot of codebases following this format  in setup.cfg file but my question is if you ignore E501 then you code accepts any number of characters per line in a module, again why they are using max-line-length?

Answer (score 4):

I believe this is because the default characters per line is 82, so they ignore that so it can exceed that number, but then set a larger limit (120 in your case)

Comment: if my code exceeds 120 char  then it will through an E501 error right

Comment: I forget if it's exactly E501 you get back but you definitely get an error back if you run the flake8 test, yes

Comment: some how my flake8 is ignoring even the line is greater then 120 char  and i have setup.cfg  with above configuration

Comment: Ah apologies, maybe you can't ignore e501 then, try removing that but keeping the max-line-length. Does that work?

Comment: the answer is the either ignore the fault entirely OR set the max-line-length.